# Is there a CEF(Chromium Embedded Framework) based chm viewer?

Tags: windows, chromium-embedded, chm

Windows self integrated CHM viewer is fine, but it always use internal Internet Explorer, For some computers that have low version of Internet Explorer do not support advanced HTML and CSS features.

So is there some alternative software for CHM viewer?

Comment: Which versions of Internet Explorer do you mean?  As a technical writer or help author have you tried to add a special tag like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` to your HTML file <head> section?

Comment: Please see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796897/1981088

Comment: make a webserver that serves chm content?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few [alternatives to the Microsoft CHM Help viewer](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-html-help/) with various levels of quality and evolution throughout the years. It is highly plausible that the cross-platform ones such as [Okular](https://kde.org/applications/office/org.kde.okular) or [xCHM](https://github.com/rzvncj/xCHM) are using a WebKit based web-browser to display the topic content. [WebKit](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) is the browser engine used by Google Chrome and therefore CEF.

That being said, a technical writer should carefully think if it makes sense to use a third-party CHM help viewer, as it would imply:

- The installation of a potentially large and unknown application on the end-user's computer;
- Possible difficulties for the end-user to operate this new application, which would be dramatic as its purpose is to help her in the first place;
- The possibility that the installation or use of this new application "steals" the .CHM extension and opens every CHM help file in the future, making it a nightmare for novice users;
- Extensive tests to make sure that the chosen application correctly works with the CHM help files as they evolve;

One possible solution would be to consider another documentation format such as an online HTML documentation web-site (which can be opened using any web-browser), or a cross-platform QT help file (which would require the installation of the Qt framework).
A single source help authoring tool such as [HelpNDoc](https://www.helpndoc.com/), [RoboHelp](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RoboHelp) or [Flare](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/MadCap_Software) can be used to simplify the process of creating multiple documentation formats for different audiences: most of them can produce basic CHM help file for the Windows operating system, as well as full-featured HTML documentation web-sites and printable Word or PDF manuals without too much extra efforts.